# Edit dynamically created li into input for a to do list jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a to do list and I can swap,delete and edit my li.

Right now I use the contenteditable prop for my edit function. 
I would like to replace that with an input when I press the editButton and save the input in list if I press editButton again, but I don't know how to do it.

This is my html code:

```js
var aux = 0;

$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('#button').click(
      function() {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=listItem]').val();
        var editTxt = $('<input type="text"/>');
        if (toAdd == '')
          alert("U must input something!");
        else {
          $("#list").append('<li><span>' + toAdd + " </span>  <button class='edit'>" + "Edit</button>" +
            " <button class='delete'>" + "Delete</button></li>");
          $('input').val("");
        }
      });


    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
      $(this).closest("li").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
      if ($(this).closest("li").find("span").prop("contenteditable") == "true")
        $(this).closest("li").find("span").prop("contenteditable", false).focus();
      else
        $(this).closest("li").find("span").prop("contenteditable", true).focus();
    });

    $('ol').sortable();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
  <h>My list:</h>
  <form name="toDoList">
    <input type="text" name="listItem" />
  </form>

  <button id="button">Add</button>
  <br/>
  <ol id="list"></ol>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="v4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you could use $(selector).html(content) to find your existing <li>'s & then add the content of the input as a new <li>.

Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Ben I think I should find the span from list for each element, replace the whole item with a new input ,not the one used for adding items, so I can edit the item and then save the input in span place.

Comment: @Netheru Just add hidden input along with span. and on Edit click check if span is visible then show input with span html and if hidden then replace input value to span and hide input field. Check code snippet in answer

Comment: @yogendarji Thank you sir !

Comment: @Netheru Please mark answer as correct if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Just add `hidden` input along with span. and on Edit click check if span is visible then show `input` with span html and if hidden then replace `input` value to span and hide input field.

```js
var aux = 0;

$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('#button').click(
      function() {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=listItem]').val();
        var editTxt = $('<input type="text"/>');
        if (toAdd == '')
          alert("U must input something!");
        else {
          $("#list").append('<li><span>' + toAdd + "</span> <input hidden></input><button class='edit'>" + "Edit</button>" +
            " <button class='delete'>" + "Delete</button></li>");
          $('input').val("");
        }
      });


    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
      $(this).closest("li").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
      /*  if ($(this).closest("li").find("span").prop("contenteditable") == "true")
          $(this).closest("li").find("span").prop("contenteditable", false).focus();
        else
          $(this).closest("li").find("span").prop("contenteditable", true).focus(); */

      if ($(this).closest("li").find("span").is(':visible')) {
        var val = $(this).closest("li").find("span").html();
        $(this).closest("li").find("span").hide();
        $(this).closest("li").find("input").show();
        $(this).closest("li").find("input").val(val);
        $(this).html("Save");
      } else {
        var val = $(this).closest("li").find("input").val();
        $(this).closest("li").find("input").hide();
        $(this).closest("li").find("span").show();
        $(this).closest("li").find("span").html(val);
        $(this).html("Edit");
      }


    });

    $('ol').sortable();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
  <h>My list:</h>
  <form name="toDoList">
    <input type="text" name="listItem" />
  </form>

  <button id="button">Add</button>
  <br/>
  <ol id="list"></ol>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="v4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of $(this).closest("li").find("span")... try $(this).prev().prev() & for $(this).closest("li").find("input") ... try $(this).prev().. This will reduce your traversing through the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/z7bjdv01/1/),

```
 $(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
      var span = $(this).parent().children(':first-child'); // gets the first input (edit input)
      if (span.children().length > 0) { // checks if it is edit mode or not
        var spanText = span.children(':first-child').val(); // gets the inputs value
        span.html(spanText); // set it to input
      } else {
        var spanText = span.text(); // get span input 
        var input = "<input value=" + spanText + ">"; // set it to input for edit
        span.html(input); // paste inside span
      }
    });
```

Hope helps,